# Gandi and Heroku set up issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

I have a domain from gandi.net, I'm trying to make it point to my heroku app. I followed several tutorials and steps, I almost did it but I'm getting this **Access to bamboo HTTP endpoint denied**

```
This is my zone file: 

@ 10800 IN A 174.129.212.2
@ 10800 IN A 75.101.145.87
@ 10800 IN A 75.101.163.44
www 10800 IN CNAME myapp.herokuapp.com
```

And I already added the domains using heroku CLI. myapp.com and also www.myapp.com

Any idea?

Answer (score 6):

Gandi does NOT support ALIAS/ANAME. How to point both www subdomain and bare domain at your Herokuapp

```
@ 10800 IN A 217.70.184.38 #this is Gandi's IP address
www 10800 IN CNAME your-app.herokuapp.com.
```

- a web forwarding set up.(301 permanent redirect from bare domain to www.projectborrow.com). For Gandi, web forwarding is not adjusted in the zone files, it's a separate page that you access from the domain page in the box on the upper right (where you do email).

Comment: This is out of date. Gandi.net DOES support ALIAS

Answer (score 4):

You need to get rid of the A records because Heroku no longer supports them. `www.yourdomain.com` should still work with that config though.

If you want to point the naked domain at your app on Heroku then you'll need to create an [ALIAS record](http://blog.dnsimple.com/2011/11/introducing-alias-record/) and I'm not sure if Gandhi supports these.

Comment: They do. (now.)

Answer (score 0):

To do it right, you would need an ALIAS record for the apex of your domain.

Gandi does not support ALIAS records yet, but you can vote for them to implement them [here](https://www.gandi.net/domain/wishlist/).