# Setting up domain service to work with Heroku using Gandi

Tags: heroku, dns

Let me keep this as simple as possible. I have looked at a bunch of other posts related to this but haven't found an answer :(. I am hosting my web app on Heroku and using Gandi as my domain provider.

Note: The top answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854091/gandi-net-and-heroku-domain-routing?noredirect=1&lq=1) post is what I used as my basis.

A few days ago I set up web forwarding on Gandi so that my mydomain.gg forwards over to www.mydomain.gg. I also set up custom domains in Heroku. It looks like this:

```
*.mood.gg    wildcard.mood.gg.herokudns.com
www.mood.gg  www.mydomain.gg.herokudns.com
mood.gg      mydomain.gg.herokudns.com
```

I then went into Gandi and added these to my zone file so it looks like this:

```
@   A   217.70.184.38
*   CNAME   mydomain.gg.herokudns.com.  
www CNAME   www.mydomain.gg.herokudns.com.
```

The A tag is there for the web forwarding where the IP points to a Gandi IP. Heroku changes IP addresses frequently, which is why I use CNAME.

Cool!

**This all worked perfectly for 3 days, where I didn't touch my zone file or Heroku app for those 3 days *at all.***

**So here is where the oddness begins.** I upgraded my Heroku server to a more expensive plan and pushed some new code to it as well. A few hours later, my root domain mydomain.gg breaks and doesn't forward over to www.mydomain.gg. If I go directly to www.mydomain.gg it works perfectly.

So my question comes down to, where did this break? I never touched my Gandi zone file. All I did was push to my Heroku server and it seemed to break the web forwarding with Gandi. How did pushing to Heorku cause something to mess up with Gandi where all I'm specifying is a Heroku DNS that didn't change at all?

Another thing is, Gandi says they don't support naked domain CNAMEs which is why I use web forwarding. But then whats the point of this line in my zone file:

```
*   CNAME   mood.gg.herokudns.com.
```

Any help would be appreciated!